# use of undeclared identifier 'renameat2'

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm supposed to use this 'renameat2', in an android cpp project.

This function should be declared in stdio.h
however, for some reason, it's not declared in the stdio.h version the app is trying to use.

How do I update it to the latest one ?